# Data transfer from one Database server to another in Java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sybase

I don't really ask a lot of questions but This time, it's too much. Here's the problem.
I have these two database (Sybase) servers and there's this database with over 90 tables but i need to archive only 20 tables.

These tables are however quite large and can contain up to 90million records. So here's the deal. Currently, what I do is that

- For the big tables (alot of records), I create a temp table and copy from the temp table to the destination but running an insert for each statement.
- After the copying is done, i drop the temp table created.

Now, I've tried other methods like for instance.

1. Up to now, the multi threading is just okay but the speed of archival is not good enough. for instance, it can archive up to 1.6M records within  one hour. That is not good enough  for my Boss.

Kindly advice on any other solution, approach or thought you'd think can help. Please not that all solutions are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Forget the Java part and do it all with the database tools. If you use a programming language you will have to move the data in both directions over the network. Doing it with the database itself will be orders of magnitude faster and more reliable.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that the user needs an application, with a UI. what would you suggest about that..?

Comment: Why do you require a User Interface? if you are dealing with large data you cannot initiate that request without being `async`

Comment: The users need to monitor and know how the tool is running. they just need a UI so they can work easily (automated)

Comment: @KennethClark if you know what I mean. Novice users need a UI. part of the requirements.

Comment: @KennethClark if you know what I mean. Novice users need a UI. part of the requirements. Do you think the UI is partly responsible for the detail.?

Comment: There are Replication Tools for databases which have specific analytic s which will be more useful then trying to do it yourself. I would expect if you create an interface you will be maintaining a nigtmare of users asking for performance improvements.

Comment: Do you insert each record with java?

Comment: @KennethClark it is a nightmare trust me.

Comment: @MichaelKazarian yes i do it with java. I generate inserts on the fly and then do an insert.

Comment: If you are using Sybase ASE, you may also want to look at Component Integration Services (CIS).  It allows you to interact with a remote DB through your local Sybase ASE instance. It's similar to mounting a remote hard drive to your local system.

Comment: WOW, @MichaelGardner, that looks owesome. I'm gonna check it out. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do not copy such amount of data by yourself. Create database jobs to copy/archive tables. And monitor the output/logs of those jobs in your application. It will be much faster.

Comment: Well the thing is that it's over a network so unless your telling me that there is a way to transact between two sybase servers. I'd be the happiest to hear it

Answer (score 1):

1. Generate SQL executive script and pass it to database. It mean fetch all records from `select` statement and create `insert/update` statements:

`String query = "UPDATE OR INSERT INTO TABLE (ID, VALUE) VALUES (9, 2) MATCHING (IDPRODUCT, COUNT); "+
"UPDATE OR INSERT INTO TABLE (ID, VALUE) VALUES (10, 1) MATCHING (IDPRODUCT, COUNT); "+
"COMMIT WORK;";`

2. If Sybase can connect to other Sybase instance create procedure for execute previous clause. For FierebirdSQL it possible through [`ON EXTERNAL`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-psql-execstat.html#langrefupd25-psql-execstat-on-external) and [`EXECUTE PROCEDURE` with procedure name as parameter](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-psql-execstat.html#langrefupd25-psql-execstat-nooutput) instructions.

`The users need to monitor and know how the tool is running.` For each commited table update user interface.

Comment: That is just what I do. I generate these (INSERT) statements from the select ResultSet and as i iterate through it, I perform an insert...

Comment: Push `all` modify statements to database.

Comment: I see it. thanks for the update. What would be the impact of adding the matching clause... if I may ask?

Comment: @OluDoug It's my bug. I moved down `For each commited table update user interface.` after comment. Other words after call stored procedure for pump data you can update user interface.